# Java OCR Unkown Errors

Tags: java, ocr, aspose

I am Facing some problems while using aspose.ocr library in netbeans. The programm is given below and the problems too.

```
package ocr;

import com.aspose.ocr.ImageStream;
import com.aspose.ocr.OcrEngine;
import java.io.*;




public class OCR {


public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException  {

   com.aspose.ocr.OcrEngine engine=new com.aspose.ocr.OcrEngine();
   String image="D:\\ocr.bmp";
   String resource="H:\\Software\\java_jdk\\aspose-ocr-17.01-java.zip";
   engine.setResource(new FileInputStream(resource));
   engine.setImage(ImageStream.fromFile(image));
   com.aspose.ocr.Ilanguage language=Language.lead("English");

    engine.getLanguages().addLanguage(language);
    engine.process();
    System.out.print(engine.getText());

}

}
```

**Problems:**
1. In the line " engine.setResource(new FileInputStream(resource));" I am getting the message regarding "setResource "

2. In the line " com.aspose.ocr.Ilanguage language=Language.lead("English");"..I am getting two errors regarding language

3.in the line " engine.getLanguages().addLanguage(language);" ..I am getting error regarding laguage.

Please help me.

Comment: You are getting downvotes and close votes because you did not include the _actual_ error messages.  Your paraphrasing of the messages makes the question unanswerable.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform OCR operation on a scanned image containing writing other than English, it requires loading language specific resources. Language specific resources for .Net & Java are same. English is the default language that needs no settings. The resources can be downloaded from link [Resources](https://downloads.aspose.com/ocr/net/resources/). Following is the sample Java code snippet:

```
String imagePath = "french_sample.jpg";
OcrEngine ocr = new OcrEngine();

ocr.setImage(ImageStream.fromFile(imagePath));

ocr.getLanguageContainer().clear();
ocr.getLanguageContainer().addLanguage(
com.aspose.ocr.LanguageFactory.load(
"French_language_resource_file_for_Aspose.OCR_for_.NET_3.2.0.zip"));

if (ocr.process()) 
{
     System.out.println(ocr.getText());
} 
else
{
     System.out.println("Error reading image");
}
```

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.